# "Navigate to file" from favorite window in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In our project we have several files with the same name, when I try to open file(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>), it lists out all the files in my project matches with the given name. I thought of adding the required files to "favorite" and open from that window.

Is there any settings which can be done, so that when I try to navigate to a file, first show the files stored under favorite and then followed by that from other directories?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such setting.

Note that you can enter a part of the path in Goto File dialog. For example, if you need to navigate to index.html in the "shop" directory, you can enter "sh/in". It will show only the index.html files under the "shop" directory or other directories that have "sh" in the path, and not all of the index.html files in your project.